# How to get arguments to a decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Is there a way to get the arguments to a decorator given the function being wrapped? For example,

```
@job('default')
def update_index():
    call_command("update_index", remove=True) 


func = update_index
args = ?? # How to use 'func' to get the string 'default' here?
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to apply here. He is looking to get the arguments of the wrapped function, not the arguments of the decorator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can't.

`job('default')` is executed *first*; what that returns is used as the decorator; in essence, python does:

```
def update_index():
    call_command("update_index", remove=True) 
update_index = job('default')(update_index)
```

As such, `job('default')` could return *anything*. It could return a function that does nothing but return it's argument:

```
def job(value):
    return lambda f: f
```

This does nothing with `value`, and the returned 'decorator' is a no-op, it returns the original function *unchanged*.

For *specific* decorators, it may well be that they leave behind a closure or extra attributes we could introspect. But that really depends on the *specific* decorator.

Comment: I don't follow how the return value of `job('default')` comes into play here...I don't want to execute the decorator or `update_index()`

Comment: @jess: that's how the decorator syntax *works*. The bit after `@` is an expression. It is evaluated. The result is the decorator callable, it is then called with the function-to-decorate being passed in, the return value is the used for the named function instead.

Comment: @jess: `update_index()` is not executed here. But the decorator *is*, that's what is meant by applying a decorator.